# List of number of values in a range (Google Spreadsheets or Excel)

Tags: excel

I asked a similar question a little while ago. I was basically just learning how to count the number of recurrences of a string in a range (using =COUNTIF()). I am now doing a very similar task, but I think it will be much more complex to solve.
So say for example I have a data set:

Gnar
Gnar
Anivia
Gnar
Sejuani
Malzahar
Malzahar
Malzahara
Sejuani
Gnar

(Yes I am doing a stats sheet for me and my team for League of Legends)

So I would like to ultimately have a pie chart or something with my percentage play of each champ (this will be a huge data set of 100's of games per year)
How can I have a pie chart or some other chart that shows the number of times each separate string appears in a range without me already having put it in.

If you need any clarification let me know!

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PivotTables` and `PivotCharts` will be your friends on this one...

Place those names in a column, let's say column `A`. It would be wise to insert a row header, I used **Title** in the my example.

Select the range, and do `Insert > PivotTable`.  Once the PivotTable is created, drag **Title** (or whatever you named the header) down to `Row Labels`.  Next drag **Title** again the `Values` section.  Icing on the cake would be drag **Title** yet again, to `Values` and then click the second count column created in the PivotTable and elect for `Show Values As > % of Column Total`.

If you just want a bar chart, you can remove the percent column, click on the Pivot Table, and hit `ALT+F1` to create a PivotChart.  Although, you will probably want to apply some cleanup formatting to get the final result below.

[image: Pivot01]

[image: Pivot02]

[image: Pivot03]

[image: Chart01]

[image: Chart_Final]

Comment: Excellent (upvoted)! I was just couple seconds behind before posting essentially the same solution using Pivot Table. And, btw, similar solution has been suggested by @Mike Fitzpatrick here: http://superuser.com/questions/284078/excel-formula-to-find-frequency-of-occurrence-of-unique-words-in-a-column. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in depth answer! I was wondering, I will try to use this same approach, but I am using this on google spreadsheets and it has different things. Would you know how to do it there (I shall give it a try)

Comment: Should be pretty similar in Google Spreadsheets. Not sure if you can recreate the "% of Total" feature without a formula, but you should be able to get a basic Pivot Table going via `Data > Pivot table report...`